# How to import Deepgram nodeJS SDK in VueJS 3 project

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, sdk

I'm trying to install [Deepgram SDK](https://developers.deepgram.com/sdks-tools/sdks/node-sdk/) for Node.JS and use it in my VueJS 3 application. Each time I try to import the SDK it gives me several errors.

how can I use Node SDK in my vue project?

my main.js

```js
import { createApp } from "vue";
import App from "./App.vue";
import router from "./router";
import "./tailwind.css";
import AudioVisual from "vue-audio-visual";

const { Deepgram } = require("@deepgram/sdk");

createApp(App).use(router).use(AudioVisual).mount("#app");
```

```js
 WAIT  Compiling...                                                                                          11:45:31 PM

Compiling...


 ERROR  Failed to compile with 5 errors                                                                      11:45:32 PM

 error  in ./node_modules/@deepgram/sdk/dist/httpRequest.js

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'F:\Projects\be-readable\node_modules\@deepgram\sdk\dist'

fy") }'
        - install 'https-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
        resolve.fallback: { "https": false }
 @ ./node_modules/@deepgram/sdk/dist/projects.js 40:20-44
 @ ./node_modules/@deepgram/sdk/dist/index.js 6:17-38
 @ ./src/main.js 11:15-39

ERROR in ./node_modules/@deepgram/sdk/dist/transcription/liveTranscription.js 23:36-58
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'querystring' in 'F:\Projects\be-readable\node_modules\@deepgram\sdk\dist\transcription'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
        - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "querystring": require.resolve("querystring-es3") }'
        - install 'querystring-es3'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
        resolve.fallback: { "querystring": false }
 @ ./node_modules/@deepgram/sdk/dist/transcription/index.js 40:26-56
 @ ./node_modules/@deepgram/sdk/dist/index.js 7:22-48
 @ ./src/main.js 11:15-39

ERROR in ./node_modules/@deepgram/sdk/dist/transcription/preRecordedTranscription.js 54:36-58
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'querystring' in 'F:\Projects\be-readable\node_modules\@deepgram\sdk\dist\transcription'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
        - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "querystring": require.resolve("querystring-es3") }'
        - install 'querystring-es3'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
        resolve.fallback: { "querystring": false }
 @ ./node_modules/@deepgram/sdk/dist/transcription/index.js 41:33-70

webpack compiled with 6 errors
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use the node SDK in this way, but you can open a connection to Deepgram in your Vue frontend by creating a browser Websocket:

```js
// open connection to Deepgram
   const socket = new WebSocket("wss://api.deepgram.com/v1/listen", [
      "token",
      "YOUR_API_KEY",
    ]);
```

There would be no need to require Deepgram in the main.js file where you have

```js
const { Deepgram } = require("@deepgram/sdk");
```

Your API key lets you connect directly to DG, although including that in the browser is not secure and would expose your key.

Then inside socket.onopen() you can write all your logic to listen to the stream. I would use an HTML audio player like this:

```html
<audio src="http://lyd.nrk.no/nrk_radio_alltid_nyheter_aac_h" controls></audio>
```

Then use the MediaStreams API to get the browser microphone, listen for the audio that is playing, and send that data to Deepgram.

This blog post has html and vanilla javascript that would work the same in Vue.js https://developers.deepgram.com/blog/2021/11/live-transcription-mic-browser/. No need for the SDK.

Comment: Thanks and I already built a project that can listen to sound and send data to Deepgram. I was just hoping that Deep gram would be able to listen by it's own to a podcast and return the transcription. What made me believe it was possible is this one here https://developers.deepgram.com/documentation/getting-started/streaming/

Comment: I thought to myself "since that is possible with NodeJS SDK why can't I find a way to implement it with vanilla JS or VueJS" but apparently it's impossible so your solution would do that trick as a work around thanks so much

Comment: I found this https://gist.github.com/revolunet/e620e2c532b7144c62768a36b8b96da2

Will it be possible to send the audio from my browser to Deepgram after converting it to audio

Comment: There is no way to set Deepgram Authorization header like node WebSocket in browser/client WebSocket. but [
      "token",
      "YOUR_API_KEY",
    ] will do the job, thanks for the wonderful answer!!!

Answer (score 2):

The Deepgram Node SDK doesn't support browser-based use cases. It is strictly server-side as it requires Node specific methods like fs and querystring.

You can still use the Deepgram API with Vue though. You'll just need to hit the API directly. The [API reference](https://developers.deepgram.com/api-reference/#transcription-streaming) is a good resource to see what's possible as far as features and parameters to send. Also, [this blog post](https://developers.deepgram.com/blog/2021/11/live-transcription-mic-browser/) has some sample code that will show you how to access the mic in your browser and send it to Deepgram.

Comment: Thanks! I already built an app that can access mic, send the data to Deepgram and receive the transcript which was very exciting for me to build another one that I will be able to pass a podcast or live audio link to Deepgram and get transcription but since I'm using vue i'ts almost impossible to do that. I spent 2 days motivating myself that I would figure out a way to do it with only Vue but It was stupid as the technology to do so doesn't exist in the real world :D

Comment: I tried fetch, async, axios and all I could find. It's just not working with VueJS or vanilla JS. must be Node or Python I guess.

Comment: You can't pass a live audio link to DG, but you could pass the audio to it. Looking at the Getting Started guide for live streaming (https://developers.deepgram.com/documentation/getting-started/streaming/#write-the-code), you'd have to modify it to fetch the audio and pipe it directly to the websocket.

Comment: Got it. I guess I should've checked the possibility before spending 2 days trying to solve unsolvable issue :D Thanks for the help.

Comment: I found this gist.github.com/revolunet/e620e2c532b7144c62768a36b8b96da2 Will it be possible to send the audio from my browser to Deepgram after converting it to audio

Comment: That should work